# Python Stripe - Get all customers that unsubscribed from a specific plan

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Say I have a plan called `'pro-plan'`, listing all its existing subscribers is quite straightforward

```
for subscriber in stripe.Subscription.all().auto_paging_iter():
    # do something with this subscriber
```

What I was wondering, is how can figure out users that unsubscribed in a given timeframe?

For example, given `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` how can I find users who have unsubscribed from a specific plan?

Comment: Tell us what happens on unsubcribing. Do you remove the entries from the table or not? Also you need to put some more information or code for better help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, when someone unsubscribe, I use `.retrieve` to get the subscription, and then I call `sub.delete()` on the retrieved subscription

Comment: That's the thing, you want to get the information that you are deleting. So if someone wants to unsubscribe the plan you should have some field in your model to know whether user has that plan activated or not. And change that field from active to inactive on unsubscription instead of deleting the entry from `Subscription` model

Comment: The thing is I am a third party, using customer's tokens to manage their stripe, so I don't really control what they do on unsubscription. Is it a normal practice to just cancel it without deleting?

Comment: A turnaround solution is to make a model on your side to store the information about subscriptions and change it accordingly when unsubcribed. Is it possible for you? Because if the third party doesn't provide that info then you have to implement it by yourself

Comment: I see on the docs that the Subscription model has "canceled_at" field, I imagine this one is updated once `.delete()` is called - I wonder does a subscription never deletes itself entirely? Does it only change status to cancelled? Or is there a time I cannot query it anymore ?

Comment: Here you go you have the solution here. Since the info you needed should be present. Yes stripe doesn't delete this info because it offers much value. May be in yours case too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe lets you retrieve canceled subscriptions by passing `status=canceled` when [listing subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_subscriptions) (though you need to be on API version [2016-07-06](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2016-07-06) or more recent to do so).

You'd then need to filter on your end to keep the subscriptions that were canceled during the timeframe you're interested in, using each subscription's [`canceled_at`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object-canceled_at) attribute.

```
subscriptions = stripe.Subscription.list(plan='pro-plan', status='canceled')
for subscription in subscriptions.auto_paging_iter():
    if start_timestamp <= subscription.canceled_at <= end_timestamp:
        # Do something with subscription
```

Comment: I didn't know `status='canceled'` is possible, thanks, exactly what I needed.
Isn't there a way to limit the timestamp inside the query? Something similar to `created={'gt': start_timestamp,  'lt': end_timestamp}`?

Comment: Also, are there more options than 'active' and 'cancelled' ?

Comment: @bluesummers You can view the different possible values for `status` here: https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_subscriptions-status. Unfortunately, it's not possible to send `canceled_at` as a parameter when listing subscriptions, so the filtering has to be done on your end.